# Oracle alter index to allow index on null values

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

Unfortunately one column of a huge table has null of half of the data, so when query

```
select count(*) from huge_table where half_null_col is null;
```

will be a performance disaster even if it is already indexed:

```
create index half_null_col_idx on huge_table(half_null_col asc);
```

There are two questions:

1. Oracle 11g should [support a constant expression to index on null values](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_null_idx.htm), but sorry I went through oracle doc but couldn't find explicit official document about it. Please share the reference if anyone knows
2. how to alter the index instead of `drop` and `create` again to avoid performance issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have at least four options that come to my mind at this moment:

1. Create the "constant expression" index...

   ```
   create index half_null_col_idx
   on huge_table (half_null_col, 1);
   ```
2. Create a bitmap index on the table. Bitmap indexes allow for indexing NULLs as well...

   ```
   create bitmap index half_null_col_idx
   on huge_table (half_null_col);
   ```
3. Create an index on a function-based NULL-remapped-to-something values and use that remapped NULL in your queries instead of querying for NULLs...

   ```
   create index half_null_col_idx
   on huge_table (nvl(half_null_col, '<a value that does not appear in the values of the column>'));

   select *
   from huge_table
   where nvl(half_null_col, '<a value that does not appear in the values of the column>')
       = '<a value that does not appear in the values of the column>'
   ;
   ```
4. Repartition the table so that NULL values go all into one partition and the rest of the values into different partition/partitions...

   ```
   create table huge_table_2
   partition by list (half_null_col)
   (
       partition pt_nulls values (null),
       partition pt_others values (default)
   )
   as
   select *
   from huge_table;
   ```

---

If you select only `count(*)` from the table then the bitmap index might be your best option.

If you want to use the full data rows from the table elsewhere (in a join to another table or to export them to CSV or whatever), then the repartitioning might be your best option.

If you can't/don't want to repartition the table and you can't create the bitmap index (e.g., due to heavy concurrent DML activity on the table), then the "constant expression" index or the "NULL-remapped-to-something" index might be your best option.

---

To answer your original questions:

1. Oracle internally approaches them as "function-based indexes". Perhaps do a search for this term.
2. You can't. But there's no relevant performance overhead for online index drop+create afaik. Oracle DB is good enough to take care of the "multitasking" stuff here - creating your index along with your application working virtually as fast as before. If you need to recreate an index, just do so. And if you go for the "constant expression" option, you can create the new index first, drop the old one afterwards.

Comment: thumbs up for the great answer :)